# Specifying action in OperationContract results in no action generated in WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, tfs, wsdl, .net-4.5

I have a strange problem I have been pulling my hair out over.  I am trying to create a TFS event handler service in WCF, and part of the requirement is to generate a SOAP 1.2 envelope with specific namespaces and actions.

The basic interface looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
public interface ITfsNotificationService
{
    [OperationContract(Action="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify", ReplyAction="*")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
    void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml, SubscriptionInfo SubscriptionInfo);
}
```

However, when I attempt to access this service with the WcfTestClient I get an error, as well as no Methods show up in the interface:

```
The contract 'ITfsNotificationService' in client configuration does not 
match the name in service contract, or there is no valid method in this
contract.
```

However, if I remove the action property from the operation contract, it runs fine (but will have the wrong Action method, which includes the interface name) and without any error.  Clearly the error is referring to the second half of the message (**Or there is no valid method in this contract**)

When I look at the generated WSDL, there are no operation elements generated when using the action property, but there is when I just specify an empty `[OperationContract]`.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong here?

FYI, this is based on the sample here:  http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/how-to-use-wcf-to-subscribe-to-the-tfs-2010-event-service-rolling-up-hours.aspx

Comment: Have you tried to specify a similar namespace in the reply? Something like this: reply="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/ReplyNotify"

Comment: @RicardoPontual - It doesn't matter if I include the ReplyAction or not.  Same problem.

Comment: I usually to keep operation contract without action/reply. They are used to customize your message, but in your example they will not change a lot, because the default name for a action (if it is missing) is: [namespace of service contract]/[service contract name]/[operation name], that will be: http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/serviceclass/notify, so you can left your operationcontract without the action attribute.

Comment: @RicardoPontual - No.  The action cannot have the service contract name in it, otherwise TFS will not recognize it, that's why you have to specify the name which does NOT include the contract name.

Comment: Understood. Try to specify the action name and remove replyAction, like this:
[OperationContract(Action="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify", Name = "Notify")]

Comment: @RicardoPontual - as I said already, I've done both.  There's no difference.  The only thing that generates the action WSDL is removing the action property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious about this, so I've tried here and worked.
Here is what I did:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
    public interface ITfsNotificationService
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify", Name = "Notify", ReplyAction = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/ResponstToNotify")]
        [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
        void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml, SubscriptionInfo SubscriptionInfo);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
    public class Service1 : ITfsNotificationService
    {
        public void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml, SubscriptionInfo SubscriptionInfo)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

[image: My test]

[image: Wsdl]

Comment: I don't know why its working now, when it wasn't before.  But removing the ReplyAction did fix it this time.  Thanks.